# Como transfomar a linha de uma tabela em coluna

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou quebrando a cabeça com um problema, preciso que as informações de uma coluna, construída através de consulta, se transforme em linha (cabeçalho da consulta).

Vi alguns tutoriais e dividas relacionadas mas não consegui implementar:

- PIVOT - não consegui implementar no mysql;
- CASE THEN - De início deu
  certo, o problema é que ele continuou duplicando a linhas por
  usuário,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
SELECT 
usuario,
op_nome,      
CASE WHEN (YEAR(cl_data_cadastro)='2016' AND MONTH(cl_data_cadastro) ='1') THEN cl_idade ELSE NULL END AS '01/2016',
CASE WHEN (YEAR(cl_data_cadastro)='2016' AND MONTH(cl_data_cadastro) ='2') THEN cl_idade ELSE NULL END AS '02/2016',
CASE WHEN (YEAR(cl_data_cadastro)='2016' AND MONTH(cl_data_cadastro) ='3') THEN cl_idade ELSE NULL END AS '03/2016'    

FROM    
    clientes 

WHERE
    cl_data_cadastro BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31'    
GROUP BY op_usuario, YEAR(ct_data_cadastro), MONTH(ct_data_cadastro)
```

Comment: É a mesma query !? existe apenas uma ocorrencia de idade ? tente algo como max(CASE WHEN (YEAR(cl_data_cadastro)='2016' AND MONTH(cl_data_cadastro) ='3') THEN cl_idade ELSE NULL END) AS '03/2016'  com GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, tenta aplicar um `MAX` em cada coluna resultante do `CASE WHEN`.

Algo assim:

```
SELECT r.usuario,
       MAX(r.col1),
       MAX(r.col2),
       MAX(r.col3)
  FROM (SELECT 
        usuario,
        op_nome,      
        CASE WHEN (YEAR(cl_data_cadastro)='2016' AND MONTH(cl_data_cadastro) ='1') THEN cl_idade ELSE NULL END AS '01/2016',
        CASE WHEN (YEAR(cl_data_cadastro)='2016' AND MONTH(cl_data_cadastro) ='2') THEN cl_idade ELSE NULL END AS '02/2016',
        CASE WHEN (YEAR(cl_data_cadastro)='2016' AND MONTH(cl_data_cadastro) ='3') THEN cl_idade ELSE NULL END AS '03/2016'    

        FROM    
            clientes 

        WHERE
            cl_data_cadastro BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-03-31'    
        GROUP BY op_usuario, YEAR(ct_data_cadastro), MONTH(ct_data_cadastro)) AS r
 GROUP BY r.usuario
```

Substitua `co1`, `col2` e `col3` pelos nomes de suas colunas.